# set equal amount of y-ticks for every subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a nice subplot graph, but I am unable to fix the problem of an unequal number of y-ticks. In the image below, for example the "VVIX Beta" plot has only 3 ticks, while others have four to five. Ideally I would like to have five y-ticks for each graph. Similar questions have already been asked, and suggested:

```
ax1.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=5)
```

where ax1 to ax7 are the seven subplots. This however didn't work, the output seemed to ignore the command. Does anyone know an alternative approach? Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Why dont you use `plt.ylim()`? to set y limits for each plots

Comment: I think this wouldn't help me in limiting the number of y-ticks, only set a limit for the tick itself. Additionally, I don't see reason for limiting the axis considering matplotlib chooses the limits pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible options is to use *MaxNLocator*, passing:

- *nbins* as the number of ticks,
- *min_n_ticks* smaller by one from *nbins*.

Look at the following example:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def draw(ax, nBins):
    ax.plot(x,  y, 'g', label='line one', linewidth=3)
    ax.plot(x2, y2,'c', label='line two', linewidth=3)
    ax.set_title('Epic Info')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
    ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
    if nBins > 0:
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=nBins, min_n_ticks=nBins-1))
    else:
        ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins='auto'))
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid(True, color='k')

x =  [ 5, 8,10]; y =  [12.1,15.2, 6.3]
x2 = [ 6, 9,11]; y2 = [ 5.4,15.5, 7.6]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10,7), constrained_layout=True)
fig.suptitle('Global title')
draw(axs.flat[0], 4)
draw(axs.flat[1], 5)
draw(axs.flat[2], 6)
draw(axs.flat[3], 0)
plt.show()
```

As you can see, it generates 4 almost identical plots:

- 3 with explicitely defined number of *y* ticks,
- and the last with *auto* setting.

The result is:

[image]

Caution: For some *nBins* the actual number of ticks is different than
expected, but at least you can experiment with my code to draw your data.